# Can't seem to figure out how to index PDF files from my computer onto Solr Docker and ElasticSearch Docker

Tags: docker, solr

I'm an absolute beginner when it comes to Docker, ElasticSearch, and Solr. I am able to run both of the software successfully on docker but am unable to figure out how to index a folder that contains PDFs.

Elastic Search:

For Docker, I'm using elasticsearch ver 8.9 and kibana 8.9.

I am aware that one can create an index using the PUT command in DEV TOOLS for Kibana, however I have no idea how to utilize that in order to index my PDFs in my computer.
[Indexing a JSON file containing some restaurants](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TW1XU.png)

I also checked and saw that elastic search gives you the option to upload JSON and CSV files directly to it for indexing, however I don't know how to convert my PDF's to a JSON file format that is acceptable to elastic search or solr

[Homepage saying that I can upload JSON files directly to elastic search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fJvN.png)

Solr:
For Solr, I'm using version 9.3 and Zookeeper 3.9

Instead of setting up the container using command lines, I used a docker-compose.yml file that I got from a tutorial from [youtube](https://stackoverflow.com):

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  solr1:
    image: solr:9.3
    container_name: solr1
    ports:
     - "8981:8983"
    environment:
      - ZK_HOST=zoo1:2181,zoo2:2181
    networks:
      - solr
    depends_on:
      - zoo1
      - zoo2
    volumes:
    - container_data:/var/lib/backup/data
     
    

  solr2:
    image: solr:9.3
    container_name: solr2
    ports:
     - "8982:8983"
    environment:
      - ZK_HOST=zoo1:2181,zoo2:2181
    networks:
      - solr
    depends_on:
      - zoo1
      - zoo2
    volumes:
    - container_data:/var/lib/backup/data
    

  zoo1:
    image: zookeeper:3.9
    container_name: zoo1
    restart: always
    hostname: zoo1
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
      - 7001:7000
    environment:
      ZOO_MY_ID: 1
      ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=zoo1:2888:3888;2181 server.2=zoo2:2888:3888;2181 
      ZOO_4LW_COMMANDS_WHITELIST: mntr, conf, ruok
      ZOO_CFG_EXTRA: "metricsProvider.className=org.apache.zookeeper.metrics.prometheus.PrometheusMetricsProvider metricsProvider.httpPort=7000 metricsProvider.exportJvmInfo=true"
    networks:
      - solr
  
  zoo2:
    image: zookeeper:3.9
    container_name: zoo2
    restart: always
    hostname: zoo2
    ports:
      - 2182:2181
      - 7002:7000
    environment:
      ZOO_MY_ID: 2
      ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=zoo1:2888:3888;2181 server.2=zoo2:2888:3888;2181
      ZOO_4LW_COMMANDS_WHITELIST: mntr, conf, ruok
      ZOO_CFG_EXTRA: "metricsProvider.className=org.apache.zookeeper.metrics.prometheus.PrometheusMetricsProvider metricsProvider.httpPort=7000 metricsProvider.exportJvmInfo=true"
    networks:
      - solr
  

  
networks:
  solr:
volumes:
  container_data:
```

When running the Solr Container in docker, the Solr Admin UI tells me that I have no Cores and Collections right now. When I try to make a Core, it asks me to provide the following:
[Solr Admin UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJlxh.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.